# Passing a pointer type as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

The following code

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual ~Abstract()
    {}
    virtual void func(const T &param) const = 0;
};

class Concrete : public Abstract<int*>
{
public:
    virtual void func(const int *&param) const override  // watch out!
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Concrete c;
}
```

produces the following compile error at the line marked with the comment:

> error C3668: 'Concrete::func' : method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods

If I remove the `override`, this error will be shown:

> error C2259: 'Concrete' : cannot instantiate abstract class

How to derive from `Abstract<int*>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `Concrete` like this:

```
class Concrete : public Abstract<int*>
{
public:
    virtual void func(int * const &param) const override
    {}
};
```

The question is: Which part of the parameter of `Abstract<int*>::f()` is `const`?

The answer: Since `T` is `const` and `T` in `Abstract<int*>` is a pointer (to an `int`), it is the pointer that is `const` - not the `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
virtual void func(int * const &param) const override  // watch out!
```